# Code igniter - URLs switching between Dev and Prod servers

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing on one server and production on a second.

Does it make sense to use the site_url() function for all links and images? That seems a bit excessive to me....

Is there a better way that adds less overhead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two folders within your config directory, one called 'development' and one called 'production', then place a `config.php` file in each with unique info for each environment. Then whenever you push code to production, just make sure the proper environment constant is set in your `index.php`

CI will handle all the change for you after that. And yes, use `site_url()`.

**PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION IS THE ROOT OF ALL EVIL**

This is also a good [resource](http://heybigname.com/2009/11/23/managing-assets-with-codeigniter/) to look at.

You may also want to take a look at the [Caribiner Library](https://github.com/aeris2k/Carabiner) for handling assets.